# Testing Firestore Login inside Android Studio

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

Does there exist a solution where I can test Cloud Firestore queries using a mock dataset? I am using android studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has a suite of [emulators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite) that are part of the Firebase command-line interface, which includes an emulator for Cloud Firestore.

Once you [install/upgrade to the latest version of the Firebase CLI](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#install_the_local_emulator_suite), you can [pass a data set to import on start up](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#startup), and then [connect to the emulator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore) from your Android app and [run unit tests](https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite#emulator_suite_in_your_local_workflows) against it.